# OpenSSL ROP hack/backdoor(OBVIOUS)/bug

Tags: security, source-code

Is the ROP hack/BACKDOOR(obvious)/bug in OpenSSL -coded form OpenSSL
member/programer Andy Polyakov- still a problem in Tor code?

Comment: Dear Iyn roj, would you elabarate on your question? Give some background information, help us to fully comprehend your question.

Comment: I think he means the function OPENSSL_indirect_call removed by OpenBSD developers: http://freshbsd.org/commit/openbsd/f868fc6f39a2c45a6c2bab70addc92525d467904 This function allows to jump to arbitrary memory locations and some people argue it was put there deliberately to increase the attack surface on OpenSSL https://teksyndicate.com/forum/inboxexe/open-ssl-andy-polyakov-spy/179670 As far as I can see the code is still in 1.0.1f